# devise_invitable: Confirm after Invitation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, actionmailer, invite

I override **devise**'s confirm! method to send a welcome message to my users:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, 
         :rememberable, :confirmable, :validatable, :encryptable

  # ...

  # Devise confirm! method overriden
  def confirm!
    UserMailer.welcome_alert(self).deliver
    super
  end

end
```

With **devise_invitable** when the user accept the invitation and set his password the **confirm!** method is never triggered, is it possible to force it? How does devise_invitable confirms the User?

Or maybe I can override the *accept_invite* (or whatever its called) method the same way?

I want that invited users remain unconfirmed, and then confirmed upon accepting the invitation.

Thanks, any help very appreciated!

[Original Source](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/issues/90)

**UPDATE**

Looking through [devise_invitable model](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/master/lib/devise_invitable/model.rb) I found the two methods who may be causing this misbehavior:

```
  # Accept an invitation by clearing invitation token and confirming it if model
  # is confirmable
  def accept_invitation!
    if self.invited? && self.valid?
      self.invitation_token = nil
      self.save
    end
  end

  # Reset invitation token and send invitation again
  def invite!
    if new_record? || invited?
      @skip_password = true
      self.skip_confirmation! if self.new_record? && self.respond_to?(:skip_confirmation!)
      generate_invitation_token if self.invitation_token.nil?
      self.invitation_sent_at = Time.now.utc
      if save(:validate => self.class.validate_on_invite)
        self.invited_by.decrement_invitation_limit! if self.invited_by
        !!deliver_invitation unless @skip_invitation
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Figured out: https://gist.github.com/982181

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, 
         :rememberable, :confirmable, :validatable, :encryptable

  # ...

  # devise confirm! method overriden
  def confirm!
    welcome_message
    super
  end

  # devise_invitable accept_invitation! method overriden
  def accept_invitation!
    self.confirm!
    super
  end

  # devise_invitable invite! method overriden
  def invite!
    super
    self.confirmed_at = nil
    self.save
  end

private

  def welcome_message
    UserMailer.welcome_message(self).deliver
  end

end
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Just a minor remark to this with regards to validation. `accept_invitation!` might not produce a valid model, e.g. if password restrictions are not met as the invited user accepts the invitation. `self.confirm! if model.valid?` to catch this and not let the welcome email slip out in case of validation error.

Answer (score 6):

I tried benoror's answer and at first it appeared to work - but when you a user accepts the invitation and fills in the form as invalid it will actually override the token invalidating the invitation.

Instead, a callback is available to do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, 
     :rememberable, :confirmable, :validatable, :encryptable

  after_invitation_accepted :send_welcome_email


  def send_welcome_email
  end

end
```

Comment: Times have changed. this is the answer. Thanks @Dandan